# Terraform : Using for_each in module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform version 0.14.3.
I have a module for creating an Azure Network Interface Card, as below:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {

  name                = var.nic_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = var.ipconfig_name
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

Its output is defined as :

```
output "nic_id" {
     value = azurerm_network_interface.nic.id 
}
```

I am calling this module in this parent module:

```
module "NIC" {
  source = "./NIC"
  for_each = var.nics

  nic_name      = each.value.nic_name
  location      = "eastus2"
  rg_name       = "abc-test-rg"
  ipconfig_name = each.value.ipconfig_name
  subnet_id     = <subnet_id>
}

output "nic_ids" {
  value = [for k in module.NIC.nic_id : k.id]
}
```

The NIC values are defined as below:

```
nics = {
  nic1 = {
    nic_name      = "abc-nic-1"
    ipconfig_name = "nic-1-ipconfig"
  }
}
```

I want to loop around the NIC output IDs, and want them displayed.
When I run above code, I get below error in *terraform plan* :

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 15, in output "nic_ids":
  15:   value = [for k in module.NIC.nic_id : k.id]
    |----------------
    | module.NIC is object with 1 attribute "nic1"

This object does not have an attribute named "nic_id".
```

How do I get around it ?

Answer (score 6):

Your `module "NIC"` block has `for_each` set, and so the `module.NIC` symbol elsewhere in the module is a mapping from instance keys to output objects, rather than just a single output object as for a singleton module.

Terraform's error message is attempting to draw attention to that with the following message:

- `module.NIC is object with 1 attribute "nic1"`

Notice that `nic1` here is a key from your `var.nics`, and *not* one of the output values defined in your module.

Assuming that the `nic_id` output you showed here is the only one defined in that module, the `module.NIC` value would be shaped something like this:

```
{
  nic1 = {
    nic_id = "eni-e5aa89a3"
  }
}
```

It sounds like you instead want to produce a value shaped like this:

```
{
  nic1 = "eni-e5aa89a3"
}
```

If so, a suitable expression to get that result would be the following:

```
output "nic_ids" {
  value = { for k, nic in module.NIC : k => nic.nic_id }
}
```

The above means: produce a mapping with one element for each instance of the `NIC` module, whose key is the module instance key and whose value is the `nic_id` output value.

Alternatively, if it doesn't matter which id belongs to which instance then you could produce an unordered set of ids, like this:

```
output "nic_ids" {
  value = toset([for nic in module.NIC : nic.nic_id])
}
```

In this case the `for` expression only defines a local symbol `nic`, which represents the module instance object, because it doesn't do anything with the instance key. The `toset` here is to represent that the IDs are not in any particular order: that isn't strictly necessary but I think it's a good practice to make sure that any other Terraform code depending on that value doesn't *inadvertently* depend on the current arbitrary ordering of the ids, which might change in future if you add or remove elements in `var.nics`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, let me give that a try.